# Using react-color what if want to enter hex-value by typing in text box provided and if then press enter it should save that color in state?

Tags: reactjs, antd, use-state, react-color

Hey guys if you have previously worked with **react-color** I need your help!
ColorPicker (specifically I'm using **TwitterPicker**) in react-color has the option of  `colors`  where you can pass an array of hex decimal values in the array.
**But what if want to enter hex-value  by typing in the text box provided and if then press enter it should save that color in state** ?
Code has more files so here is sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-color-issue-6meczi

Useful Link's

1. https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#api-individual
2. https://ant.design/components/popover/

Comment: It's not an issue, at least three characters need to be modified!